# Does brain.js add it's own layer of randomness on top of my neural net training data?

Tags: javascript, neural-network, brain.js

Given the following code

```
var net = new brain.NeuralNetwork();

var data = [
    { input: { source: 1 }, output: { result: 0 } },
    { input: { source: 2 }, output: { result: 1 } },
    { input: { source: 3 }, output: { result: 0 } },
    { input: { source: 4 }, output: { result: 1 } },
    { input: { source: 5 }, output: { result: 0 } },
    //{ input: { source: 6 }, output: { result: 1 } },
    { input: { source: 7 }, output: { result: 0 } },
    { input: { source: 8 }, output: { result: 1 } },
    { input: { source: 9 }, output: { result: 0 } },
    { input: { source: 10 }, output: { result: 1 } },
];

net.train(data);
var output = net.run({ source: 6 });  

alert(output.result);
```

Why do repeated refreshes of the page cause the result to fluctuate?

(I get values ranging anywhere from 0.43 -> 0.51)

I'd have assumed that in any given run, an empty neural net, trained with the same data and then asked the same question, should give the same answer?

This appears to not be the case.

**Can someone explain why this is not the case?**

or alternatively (and more likely)

**What I'm doing wrong?**

Thanks